# Models create vs. update in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to have a couple of fields in my Django models, which are saved only on creation, 
and other which are saved only on update.
E.g. "date_created" and "author" vs. "date_edited" and "last_editor".

How do I achieve this and how do I create 2 different venues / workflows for saving and for updating a model, which would be valid both when saving from admin and from custom client side forms I may create?

EDIT:

Fields I'm talking about will not be present in the form, they will be created in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve the functionality for custom views and admin best place would be the save method. Secondly, if you are trying to save the edit datetime, I would suggest looking into `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` argument used with `DateTimeField` or `DateField`. They provide a way to save the value of Timstamp of creation and latest edit. Take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield). Lastly, other solution could be to use `Django Signals` which would provide you a way to call a method whenever save method is called for the model. This would help you to decouple the logic.

```
class ExModel(models.Model):
  ...
  ...

  def save(self):
     if self.id:
       #update logic here
     else:
       #New creation logic here
```

Comment: Yes, auto_now and auto_now_add seems okay.
Upvote.
Will wait if there is any more answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `save` method of your model and identify create and update there by checking if the primary key is valued or not.

```
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk: #object is being created
            self.author = 'abc'
            self.date_created = datetime.now()
        else: #object is being updated
            self.last_editor = 'abc'
            self.date_edited = datetime.now()
        super(MyModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: As with the self.pk, it ocurred to me as well. Anyway, I was hoping there would be some kind of shortcut for these things.

Comment: no need to set date on the save method. use this model definition instead:

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)